# Ajax return php value with html

Tags: php, ajax

I'm new to programming and started land job only 1 month, have no idea how to solve these issues

1: I would like to ask how can I insert php value into `location.href` with quotes?

2: Why my button is unclickable even though I leave `send?phone=` to blank?

```
"<button type='button' style='height:50%;'
onclick='location.href=https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={$num}'>
<i class='fa fa-whatsapp'></i>ere</button>"
```

[image: php]

[image: script]

Comment: You cant give a URL to onclick Event, if you want it to be clickable you have to use anchor tag not button `<a href="your url"> Text to Display</a>`

Comment: @KhnRzk Why cant pass URL to onclick event on button?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You should not _misuse_ a button for merely linking somewhere, that is not a button element's _purpose_. Use a normal link, and give it the desired button _look_, by formatting it via CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//If the button is in HTML
<button type='button' style='height:50%;' onclick='location.href=https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=<?php echo $num; ?>'><i class='fa fa-whatsapp'></i>ere</button>

//If you want the button in php
echo "<button type='button' style='height:50%;' onclick='location.href=\"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={$num}\"'><i class='fa fa-whatsapp'></i>ere</button>";
```

Comment: OMG!!Very thankful!!Now I learned the useful of backslash

Answer (score 0):

Your button should be like this.

```
<button type="button"
onclick="location.href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={$num}'">
<i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>ere</button>
```